# css not being applied completely to the tables on html5 page

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am a newbie to html5 and developing some standalone html5 pages along with their respective css for styling. My question that follows could be a very basic one but somehow after a lot of searching for solutions I decided to post my problem here with a hope to get some hints/advice.

Here goes my problem. I have a standalone html page with its css. when I open the webpage locally on my machine all the css settings are perfectly applied. Then I upload it on my dreamhost server and after the upload when I try to open the page I lose all the formatting that I have done on the tables used in the page, whereas all the other formatting looks good. The formatting goes off on the browser as well as on android webviews. I am not sure what the problem here is in regards to the rules not being applied when I upload files on the server.

Following is how I am using the table in the html page :

```
<!-- Article 1 start -->

            <div class="line"></div>  <!-- Dividing line -->

            <article id="article1"> <!-- The new article tag. The id is supplied so it can be scrolled into view. -->
                <h3>Comparison Symbols</h3>

                <div class="line"></div>

                <div class="articleBody clear">

                <p> If you’re writing programs in C, you need to use comparison symbols. The symbols C uses, their meanings, and examples are shown in the following table: </p>
                <p>
                    <table>
                              <tr>
                                <th>Symbol</th> 
                                <th>Meaning</th>
                                <th>Examples</th>
                              </tr>

                              <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                              </tr>

                              <tr>
                                <td> < </td>
                                <td>Less than</td>
                                <td>2 < 6</td>
                              </tr>

                              <tr>
                                <td>==</td>
                                <td>Equal to</td>
                                <td>5 == 5</td>
                              </tr>

                              <tr>
                                <td>></td>
                                <td>Greater than</td>
                                <td>8 > 5</td>
                              </tr>

                              <tr>
                                <td><=</td>
                                <td>Less than or equal to</td>
                                <td>4 <= 5</td>
                              </tr>

                              <tr>
                                <td>>=</td>
                                <td>Greater than or equal to</td>
                                <td>9 >= 5</td>
                              </tr>

                              <tr>
                                <td>!=</td>
                                <td>Not equal to</td>
                                <td>1 != 0</td>
                              </tr>
                    </table>            
                </p>
                </div>
            </article>
```

And following is the lines of code that I have used in the css for the table formatting :

```
/* table properties */

th {width:150px;
    text-align:left;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration: underline;}
td {text-align:left}
```

It would be a great help if someone could give some advice.

Comment: If the table CSS is in a separate file, perhaps the file cannot be found or opened. Check for 404 errors (chrome: inspection tools (Ctrl+Shift+I) => console) on the remote page. Another option is that there is another CSS file overriding these rules and that file cannot be opened locally. Check for 404 errors on localhost.

Comment: @JanDvorak : Thanks for the advice. I checked for 404 errors on both the remote as well the local page but I did not see any 404 errors. Also I have re-checked and there is only on css file in the same directory as the html page. All the other css rules except the ones for the table are working fine. Thanks for looking into this. Any other possibilities I could check ?

Comment: Can you link us to the website so we can check?

Comment: @JanDvorak : Looks like this was a problem on the server side. The file was reverting back to an old version. Everything is working fine now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css file on the server was reverting back to an older version. The problem was solved when the reverting solved and the css retained the following config :

```
th {width:150px;
text-align:left;
font-weight:bold;
text-decoration: underline;}
td {text-align:left}
```